# How can I add another plot to the \addplot command in PGFPlots?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

My goal is to add another plot to the \addplot command and this small example hopefully shows what I'm trying to do:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
procs, none
16, 6.079748e+03
32, 3.624823e+03
64, 1.685646e+03
128, 9.180763e+02
256, 5.977239e+02
512, 4.410280e+02
}\scalability

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{loglogaxis}[
    ylabel={Time (sec)},
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={\scalability}{procs},
    table/x=procs,
    set scaling/.code={
      \edef\xcol{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/x}}
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{\xcol}\of{\scalability}
      \edef\proc{\pgfplotsretval}
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/y}}\of{\scalability}
      \edef\offset{\pgfplotsretval}
      \pgfplotsset{table/y expr=\offset * \proc / \thisrowno{0}}
      \pgfplotsextra{
        \draw (1,1) -- (256,256);              % this is drawn
        \addplot table[y=none] {\scalability}; % this is not
      }
    },
    scaling/.style={
      forget plot,
      set scaling,
    },
    forget plot style={opacity=0.4},
    ]

    \addplot +[y=none,scaling] table {\scalability};
    % \addplot table[y=none] {\scalability};

  \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What I'd like to see is:

[image]

but tinkering with the .code functionality (and also `execute at end plot`) nothing seems to be able to call another `\addplot` only lower level TikZ commands (`\draw`, `\path`, etc.):

[image]

Is there any way to get another `\addplot` appended?

Comment: I think this is going to be quite hard. It would probably be easier to define a new command that calls both of the plots. Do you have a particular reason for not wanting that?

Comment: Well, for starters, the `execute` and `.code` keys seemed like the elegant way to do this. Also, if defining a `\newcommand`, it seemed quite hacky to pass optional key-value pairs down to pgfplots; i.e.

`\mynewplotcommand +[optional styles to append];`

`\mynewplotcommand [optional styles to override]`

If passing that down to pgfplots is easier than it seems, then it would indeed work.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach does not work because `\addplot` is designed to be placed within the axis -- and `\pgfplotsextra` is designed to NOT process things inside of an axis (but to postpone their processing).

If you want to use `\addplot`, you *have* to place it into the axis.

But from what I understand from your application, I believe that you can simply place your expression evaluation stuff directly in front of the plot in question:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
procs, none
16, 6.079748e+03
32, 3.624823e+03
64, 1.685646e+03
128, 9.180763e+02
256, 5.977239e+02
512, 4.410280e+02
}\scalability

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{loglogaxis}[
    ylabel={Time (sec)},
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={\scalability}{procs},
    table/x=procs,
    table/y=none,
    forget plot style={opacity=0.4},
    ]

      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/x}}\of{\scalability}
      \edef\proc{\pgfplotsretval}
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/y}}\of{\scalability}
      \edef\offset{\pgfplotsretval}

    \addplot +[forget plot] table[y expr=\offset * \proc / \thisrowno{0}] {\scalability};
    \addplot table[y=none] {\scalability};

  \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This seems to do exactly the same job as in your request - without the key definition overhead. It works because your temporaries are immediately evaluated by `\addplot`; they are not postponed (because they are necessary to evaluate coordinates).

You may want to eliminate the `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/x}` statements to improve the robustness (your example did not properly define `table/y`).

Comment: Ah, sorry I was clear :-( I was trying to do all of the above with just one command. Part of me wanted to test the capabilities of `/.code` and `execute ...` but it seems those will not do the job, correct? If that is true, then is there a way to use `\newcommand` that passes pgf keys (as I try to illustrate above in my comment to @Jake)?

Comment: Well, macros are powerful - you can surely write some top level macro which starts two separate `\addplot` commands (i.e. by extracting the code of my example). However, `\addplot` inside of `\addplot` is unsupported - and `\addplot` within `\pgfplotsextra` as well (as explained in my answer).