Why does \begin{scope}...\end{scope} seem to treat \draw and \addplot differently in this example?
The documentation for pgfplots and tikz have me thoroughly overwhelmed. Apparently I am missing something about the behavior of \draw and \addplot when using \clip. In the MWE, the second arrow (the one not at center) and the green circle are clipped as expected, but the red dots do not seem to be affected by \clip at all even though they are within scope. Why is this? Is there some inherent difference between \draw and \addplot at work? I cannot find anything about this in the documentation for either pgfplots or tikz.
My MWE:
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% Make some global settings.
\pgfplotsset{%
  compat = 1.18,
  label style = {%
    font = {\sffamily},
  },
  title style = {%
    font = {\sffamily},
  },
  major grid style = {%
    thick,
  },
  minor grid style = {%
    thin,
    color = lightgray,
    dotted,
  },
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
      title = {Plot of \( y \) vs.\@ \( x \)},
      xlabel = {independent variable \( x \)},
      ylabel = {dependent variable \( y \)},
      %width  = 207pt,     % Use ONE of these three
      %height = 240pt,     % lines to get equally
      axis equal image,   % spaced axes.
      %grid   = both,
      %anchor = origin,
      xtick  = {0,...,6}, % Use these two lines to
      ytick  = {0,...,6}, % get equally spaced axes.
      xmin   = 0,
      xmax   = 6,
      ymin   = 0,
      ymax   = 6,
      minor x tick num = 1,
      minor y tick num = 1,
    ]%
  \coordinate (Origin) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (Point) at (5,1);
  \newcommand*{\fudge}{0.1}
    \begin{scope}
      % Set a viewport for clipping.
      \draw [rotate around={atan2(0,1):(3,3)},thick] 
        (2-\fudge,2.7-\fudge) rectangle (4+\fudge,3.3+\fudge);
      \clip [rotate around={atan2(0,1):(3,3)}] 
        (2-\fudge,2.5-\fudge) rectangle (4+\fudge,3.5+\fudge);
      
      % Draw two vectors.
      \draw [rotate around={atan2(0,1):(3,3)},->,ultra thick] (2,3) -- (4,3);
      \draw [rotate around={atan2(1,1):(3,1.5)},->,ultra thick] (2,1.5) to (4,1.5);
      
      % Plot a point. It won't be visible if \clip is used and it's within scope.
      \draw [green,fill] (Point) circle (2pt);
      
      % Plot more points. \clip doesn't affect these; not sure why.
      \addplot [only marks,red] coordinates {%
        (2,1) (3,5) (1,5)
      };
    \end{scope}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output from MWE with \clip commented out:

Output from MWE with \clip not commented out:


Pgfplots does treat \addplot differently then \draw.  For one thing \addplot is executed in both passes, while \draw is only used in the second pass.  See \pgfplotsextra.

My understanding is that the stuff defined by an \addplot is stored until the end of the axes environment, at which point the clip is out of scope, whereas the \draw is drawn there and then, when the clip is still in effect.

This answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60611/218142) seems to say that \addplot can't be used with \pgfplotsextra, which explains why my naive attempt at wrapping \addplot with \pgfplotsextra generates a "Illegal unit of measure" error. Changing \addplot to three \draw commands does what I intended. Understanding the logic behind all this is proving difficult for me.

Please make your MWE more minimal - see e.g. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Without knowing in advance what the problem is, the relevant terminology, or what the possible solutions are there is no way I can judge the minimalness of what I need to show. I will thank you for taking that into consideration.

You could just try to remove something and then compile it again - to see if you get the same result. You can not tell me you are not able to figure out that the grid style or atan2 is not relevant for this question.

Marks are normally not clipped because that is what you most likely want. Partially drawn marks are bad. It is well documented and controlled by clip marker paths.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=6,
ymin=0, ymax=6,
clip marker paths=true,
]
\draw[clip] (1,1) rectangle (4,4);
\addplot[red, mark=*] coordinates {(2,1) (3,3) (3,5) (1,5)};
\fill[green] (2,2) circle[radius=2pt];
\fill[blue] (5,5) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

No clipping:

clip marker paths=false (default):

clip marker paths=true:


"Clearly documented" is a matter of opinion. Nothing about TikZ is "clearly documented" when the user doesn't know the developer's terminology, which means the user cannot possibly know where in the extensive documentation to begin looking for solutions. This is a problem with decentralized forms of documentation that dominate the entire TeX and LaTeX ecosystem.

@LaTeXereXeTaL: I did not use an appropriate terminology. What I meant to write was “well documented”.
